# Compactness of covering space implies compactness of base space ...

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm currently working on the following exercise from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> Let $p:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be a covering space with $p^{-1}(x)$ finite and non-empty for all $x \in X$. Show that $\tilde{X}$ is compact Hausdorff iff $X$ is compact Hausdorff.

I've managed to prove everything except showing that if $\tilde X$ is compact, then $X$ is compact as well. Any hint/help will be extremely useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covering map is continuous. It's also surjective*. The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

*Apparently, Hatcher's definition of covering maps allows for non-surjective maps. If you assume $X$ is connected, or path-connected, then I think the covering map must be surjective.

Comment: That makes sense. I completely forgot about the surjectivity of $p$. Thank you!

Comment: The fibres are assumed to be non-empty. Ergo $p$ is surjective.

Comment: Oh good point, I guess I didn't process the entire question!